# Java Multiplication Error

Tags: java, multiplication

When I run the following code, I get an error:

```
double i = 1;
double pound;
System.out.println("Kilograms\t Pounds");
for(i = 1; i<199; i+=2){
pound = i * 2.2;
System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + pound + "\n");
}
```

The error:

```
Kilograms     Pounds
1.0          2.2  
3.0          6.6000000005  
5.0          11.0  
7.0          15.400000002
```

Comment: Generally finishing your code helps it compile :)

Comment: by convention (if not by rule, but I do not remember my Java from freshman year that well) `import`s should be the first thing in the file.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the whole class. I had to go back and use an old question to get the formatting right. This is all inside main()

Comment: You still haven't said what the error is.  Nobody can read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter said, this is due to the imprecision of floating point numbers. To fix it, use printf, like this:

```
System.out.printf("%.0f\t\t%.1f\n",i,pound);
```

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) or [here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/software-dev/cheat-sheet-reference-printf-format-specifier-syntax) for more information on how to use printf.

Answer (score 5):

I ran this part of the code and I assume you're referrring to the precision errors, such as getting numbers like `398.20000000000005` and `407.00000000000006` instead of `398` and `407`.

This is due the limitation of expression a number in floating-point format. Some numbers that can be expressed in *decimal format* with a limited number of digits after the decimal point just cannot be represented in a *floating-point format* using limited precision, thus you will get these errors.

EDIT

I wrote my answer before you posted what you defined as the error. But nothing is different. Please see [this link](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers.aspx) for more information about floating-point precision loss.

It's also worthwhile to note that when comparing two floating-point numbers (that have been calculated) for "equality", you should specify some small value, or *delta*, which is the maximum difference between the two numbers allowed for them to be considered equal, rather than testing for absolute equality.

Comment: That's the kind of error I'm getting! So how do I fix it?

Comment: @Keith Mattix, you can cast the `double`s into `int`s, then just add ".0" to the end of the `int` (if you really want the .0).

Comment: It is a limitation of how floating-point numbers are represented, thus it cannot be inherently fixed. But if all you want to do is get rid of the last digit in those "incorrect" numbers, you can simply use something like `System.out.printf()` to format/round the number.

Comment: @fireshadow52 Then I'd lose the decimal.

Comment: @Keith Mattix Oops! I thought you *didn't* want the decimal. Well, in that case, I would do what Peter suggested and use `System.out.printf()`.

Comment: Don't truncate to an integer and the add a pretend ".0" - as that is a very specific special case of rounding :-)  printf/String.format()has the smartest rounding logic.   - also note that the error is really small.

Comment: Also note that the error is really small, so unless you are measuring the galaxy or the national debt, double is probably good to go.  For financial applications, BigDecimal is recommended though, as people normally freak out (like you did) when they see stuff like $ 0.2499996 ...

Comment: it is a double. And which code should I use? I never use printf

Answer (score 0):

The error message would help.

On the third line, System.println should be System.out.println:

```
System.out.println("Kilograms\t Pounds");
```

Comment: I added that. Sorry, but this site won't let me do a table-like spacing thing

Answer (score 0):

System doesnt have any method like println (System.out.println) also I would use integer for i.

Answer (score -1):

1. As pointed out, you didn't give a complete code sample
2. Unfortunately, you weren't specific about the exact problem, either.

I THINK you probably mean "1 * 2.2 != 2.0".

If so, the problem is "integer truncation" - when you multiply (add, subtract, divide or multiply) and integer by a float, the fractional part is LOST.

By design :)

These articles might help:

- http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/11241.aspx
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/beyondmath.html
- http://www.codestyle.org/java/FAQ.shtml#roundupdoubleint

Comment: Actually, according to your own first source: `In Java, the rule for such expressions [an int and a double] is: If either operand of an arithmetic operator is floating-point, the calculation is done in floating-point arithmetic.`

Comment: Dude - just because the EXPRESSION is done in floating point, do you think the (integer!) VALUE is somehow magically going to be displayed as floating point??? I just noticed the edited post says "double i", but I thought it was originally "int i" ... and he's printing "i"!  PS: "idiom" is every bit as important as "syntax".  If it's an "integer", it should NEVER have a name like "i".  And one could argue that programs should never have one-letter names like "i" anyway.

Comment: What do you mean? `System.out.println(1 * 2.2)` will print `2.2` because when either operand is floating point, the result is floating point. `When you multiply (add, subtract, divide or multiply) an integer by a float` the fractional part is NOT lost, try it and see. Even if it were int i, it wouldn't matter. (By the way, I didn't down-vote you)

Comment: The OP was printing a VARIABLE ("i"; originally declared "int").